# Drag content child view on ionic framework - blank screen in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have problem with ionic v1.0.0-rc.4 on iOS 8.
This is my state code:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('menu', {
    url: '/MenuView',
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'views/MenuView.html',
    abstract:true,
    controller: 'MenuCtrl'
  })
  .state('menu.trend', { 
    url: '/TrendView',
    cache: false,
    views: {
        menuContent :{
          templateUrl: "views/TrendView.html",
          controller: 'TrendCtrl'
        }
    }
  })
```

The problem is when i drag a content in the child view, the content is missing and become a blank screen. The problem only happen on iOS, i try on my android device and I can see it.

Comment: Make sure you have followed the steps provided in this blog post for working with Ionic and MobileFirst Platform: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/04/16/an-overview-of-using-the-ionic-framework-with-mobilefirst-hybrid-mobile-applications/ but right now this does not seem to be related to IBM MobileFirst unless otherwise identified. Removing tag.

Comment: i have solved this issue, 
i change the value of attribute can-swipe-back="false

Thank you

Comment: Please supply answers as Answers and not comments.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this issue, i change the value of attribute can-swipe-back="false Thank you